# Question about logic and proving negation statements

Tags: real-analysis, logic

I am currently taking an introduction to real analysis course, and I was having trouble on knowing when I can prove the negation of a statement.

I was answering this question

If $f'(x) \neq 0$, then $f$ is one-to-one.

But I was wondering if I could prove this instead:

If $f'(x) = 0$, then $f$ is not one-to-one.

I was wondering if this was valid approach to the question.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: @RobArthan In the post, the question was whether to prove "A implies B," one can instead prove "(not A) implies (not B)". This is not equivalent.

Comment: @coffeemath: the question has suffered several edits. The latest one seems to have fixed it.

Comment: The version I see has: I was answering this question

If f′(x)≠0
, then f
 is one-to-one.

But I was wondering if I could prove this instead:

If f′(x)=0
, then f
 is not one-to-one.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the Mathematics StackExchange!

The two statements that you gave (after the 12-minute edit) are *not* equivalent; you can't turn $ A \Rightarrow B $ into $ \neg A \Rightarrow \neg B $. However, you can turn it into $ \neg B \Rightarrow \neg A $; that is, if if $ f $ is not one-to-one, then $ f ' ( x ) \ne 0 $.

But there's something else that you should watch out for here.  Your statement $ A $ is a statement about $ f $ and $ x $, while your statement $ B $ is about $ f $ alone.  I suspect that $ A $ is actually a more complicated statement, such as: for each $ x $, $ f ' ( x ) \ne 0 $.  Then the negation is: for some $ x $, $ f ' ( x ) = 0 $.  Note that $ x $ is a dummy variable in these statements, so they're also statements about $ f $ alone.

Or perhaps in even more detail, you have both an interval $ I $ and a function $ f $ that's differentiable on $ I $; then $ A $ says: for each $ x $, if $ x \in I $, then $ f ' ( x ) \ne 0 $; and $ B $ says: $ f $ is one-to-one on $ I $.  Does that sound right?  (If the claim is about any differentiable function on any domain, then it's not actually true if the domain might not be an interval.  That's why I suspect that there's also an interval in the statement, either explicitly or as part of a hypothesis that the domain of $ f $ is an interval.)

In this case, $ \neg B $, the statement that $ f $ is not one-to-one on $ I $, can also be written in more detail as: for some $ x $, for some $ y $, $ x \in I $, $ y \in I $, $ x \ne y $, and $ f ( x ) = f ( y ) $.  (This is because $ B $ itself means, in detail: for each $ x $, for each $ y $, if $ x \in I $, $ y \in I $, and $ x \ne y $, then $ f ( x ) \ne f ( y ) $.)  As for $ \neg A $, that becomes: for some $ x $, $ x \in I $, and $ f ' ( x ) = 0 $.

In this form, proving $ \neg B \Rightarrow \neg A $ is indeed a good approach; you can use Rolle's Theorem (or the Mean-Value Theorem).